# PayPal recurring payments in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, recurring-billing

I'm thinking about making a subscription system.

The samples on the website I found to be difficult to follow because they are separated classes for very specific issues.

From what I understand (if I'm not wrong) the PayPal Recurring is the best choice for subscription system.

However I hope that you can help me to find a complete sample about PayPal Recurring using .NET.

Comment: Not programming related?

Answer (score 1):

I have not used recurring billing in paypal, but this looks like a good sample: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/PayPal.aspx

However, you can also use [Authorize.NET](http://www.authorize.net/) which offers recurring billing as well.